# In app purchases Cordova Plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins

I use Cordova Plugin in-app purchases for my IOS app (https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/master/doc/api.md#refresh).

I've followed exactly as their code example shows:

```
  store.register({
         id: 'credits_test',
          alias: 'credits_advance',
          type: store.CONSUMABLE
  });

  store.refresh();

 store.when("credits_test").approved(function (product) {
            product.finish();
            updateCreditsPurchased(p.token, 1, product ints[0]);
        });

    $(".btn").click(function()
    {
       store.order("credits_test");
    })
```

I don't have any validators on the store object and I use my sandbox account for testings.

Now for some reason the product state is always "valid", even on APPROVED event before I fire the "finish" event and I also see in the console log that the product is stuck in queue..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct behaviour as you have selected a product type of `CONSUMABLE`

> When finished, a consumable product will get back to the VALID state, while other will enter the OWNED state.

Try using a `NON-CONSUMABLE` product type.

Source: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/master/doc/api.md

Comment: I have to use CONSUMABLES in my case and the "valid" state is always there even inside the APPROVED event just before i call "product.finish()".

Comment: Which tool are you using to debug?
Some tools, like the Chome Debugger take a snaphopt of arrays / objects at the first instance they are opened. Maybe try saving the product.state to a variable for debug purposes?

Comment: it is the safari debugger as it is an ios app